# XSLT dynamically generate html table for any XML section

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that is dynamically generated from a series of scripts.  Each section can have name value pairs and/or a table of information.

I'm trying to create an XSLT transformation that outputs every section, and if it contains a Format='Table' dynamically generates a table.

My sample XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QAReport ReportDate="05/03/2015 14:07:33" ReportVersion="3.0" ScriptVersion="1.2015.0428.01" QAStatus="2">
  <DiskInformation Display="Disk Information">
    <Disks Format="Table">
      <Disk>
        <DriveLetter>C:</DriveLetter>
        <FoundInSBB>True</FoundInSBB>
        <StartingOffset>
        </StartingOffset>
        <BlockSize>4096</BlockSize>
        <DriveSize>50</DriveSize>
      </Disk>
      <Disk>
        <DriveLetter>D:</DriveLetter>
        <FoundInSBB>True</FoundInSBB>
        <StartingOffset>
        </StartingOffset>
        <BlockSize>4096</BlockSize>
        <DriveSize>50</DriveSize>
      </Disk>
    </Disks>
  </DiskInformation>
  <DeviceManagerInformation Display="Device Manager Information">
    <DeviceManagerErrors Format="Table" />
  </DeviceManagerInformation>
  <EventLogInformation Display="Event Log Information">
    <SystemEventLogErrors Format="Table">
      <Event>
        <EventID>10009</EventID>
        <EventTime>04/27/2015 23:14:20</EventTime>
        <EventSource>DCOM</EventSource>
        <EventMessage>The description for Event ID  -1073731815  in Source  DCOM  cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event: WCDRE56I </EventMessage>
      </Event>
      <Event>
        <EventID>10009</EventID>
        <EventTime>04/27/2015 23:14:12</EventTime>
        <EventSource>DCOM</EventSource>
        <EventMessage>The description for Event ID  -1073731815  in Source  DCOM  cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event: WCDRE56I </EventMessage>
      </Event>

    </SystemEventLogErrors>
  </EventLogInformation>
  <IISInformation Display="IIS Information">
    <IISService Display="IIS Service Status">Running</IISService>
  </IISInformation>
  <IPInformation Display="IP Information" ReportLevel="20">
    <FQDN>Server123.mydomain.com</FQDN>
    <DNSDomain Display="DNS Domain">mydomain.com</DNSDomain>
    <IPAddress Display="IP Address">10.0.0.101</IPAddress>
    <Subnet>255.255.248.0/64</Subnet>
    <Gateway>10.0.0.1</Gateway>
    <DNSServers Display="DNS Servers" Format="List">
      <DNSServer>12.0.0.1</DNSServer>
      <DNSServer>12.0.0.2</DNSServer>
    </DNSServers>
    <DNSSearchSuffixes Display="DNS Search Suffixes" Format="List">
      <DNSSearchSuffix>MyDomain.com.com</DNSSearchSuffix>
      <DNSSearchSuffix>MyOtherDomain.com</DNSSearchSuffix>
      <DNSSearchSuffix>MyThirdDomain.com</DNSSearchSuffix>
    </DNSSearchSuffixes>
    <DNSRegistrationEnabled>True</DNSRegistrationEnabled>
    <NetBIOS>Enabled via DHCP</NetBIOS>
    <WindowsFirewallDisabled>True</WindowsFirewallDisabled>
  </IPInformation>
  <ServerInformation Display="Server Information">
    <HostName>Server123</HostName>
    <OS>Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 64-bit</OS>
    <OSVersion Display="OS Version">6.1.7601</OSVersion>
    <OSServicePack Display="Service Pack">Service Pack 1</OSServicePack>
    <CPUs>1</CPUs>
    <Memory>4096</Memory>
  </ServerInformation>
</QAReport>
```

My XSLT looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt err fn" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table class="NVPair">
            <tr>
                <th>Report Date</th>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/QAReport/@ReportDate"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>QA Status</th>
                <td>
                    <xsl:if test="/QAReport/@QAStatus = 2 ">
                        <span class="QAPass">
                            <xsl:value-of select="/QAReport/@QAStatus"/> (OK)</span>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="/QAReport/@QAStatus != 2 ">
                        <span class="QAFail">
                            <xsl:value-of select="/QAReport/@QAStatus"/> (Failure)</span>
                    </xsl:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="QAReport/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/QAReport/*">
        <h3>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@Display">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Display"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </h3>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="*/.[not(@Format)]"><!-- format each NVPair first -->
            <table class="NVPair">
                <xsl:for-each select="*/.[not(@Format='Table')]">
                    <xsl:call-template name="NVPair"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="*/.[@Format='Table']"><!-- select each table in the section-->
            <xsl:call-template name="QATable"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="NVPair">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
            </th>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="QATable">
        <h4>
            <xsl:value-of select="name(*)"/>
        </h4>
        <table class="QATable">
            <xsl:for-each select="./*/*">
                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                        <xsl:call-template name="QATableRowFirst"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:call-template name="QATableRow"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="QATableRowFirst">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="QATableRow">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have a couple of questions.

1) Is there a good way to work around the first xsl:for-each loop as a template - given that the NVP sections are dynamic.

2) the Format='Table' template is pretty ugly - two for-eaches, one for rows, the next for columns - is there a better way with call-template or apply-templates?

Remember that at any time the XML can have different sections and the tables, while consistent within each section, can have any number of columns.

**Update (2015.05-13):**

Based off of @Michael.hor257k I ended up with this, which works better and is simpler.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt err fn" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes" xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/QAReportStyle.css"/>
    <table class="NVPair">...</table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/QACheck/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/QACheck/*">
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/></h3>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="*[not(@Format)]">
        <!-- format each NVPair first -->
        <table class="NVPair">
          <xsl:for-each select="*[not(@Format='Table')]">
            <xsl:call-template name="NVPair"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- select each table in the section-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[@Format='Table']"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="NVPair">
    <tr>
      <th><xsl:value-of select="name(.)</th>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="QATable" match="*[@Format='Table']">
    <h4><xsl:value-of select="name(.)</h4>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count(*) = 0">
        <p>No Rows</p>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <table class="QATable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[1]/*">
              <td><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/></td>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <tr>
              <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*[@Format='Table']"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@Format='Table']">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[1]/*">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>           
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Notes**:

1. It is assumed that all tables are at the same hierarchy level; if this is not true, use the (less efficient) instruction `<xsl:apply-templates select=".//*[@Format='Table']"/>` instead;
2. It is assumed that all tables have the same hierarchical structure;
3. There is nothing wrong with having two `xsl:for-each` instructions; the contents are so trivial that splitting them off to individual templates serves no purpose whatsoever (except to make the code less readable).

Comment: This certainly got me in the right direction.  It was a little strange since you had removed one level of templates, and my XML testing tool ended up working slightly different than asp.net.